# How to stretch cell to full screen?

Tags: swift, layout, tableview, snapkit

I have a `UIView` inside a table cell. I need to stretch my cell on full screen.

In my table view I have this:

```
table.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

But now I can't to make this.

My code is:

```
containerView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.edges.equalToSuperview()
}
    
verticalStackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.center.equalToSuperview()
    make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(20)
}
```

I need to get this:

[image]

But I have:

[image]

Comment: If you want a taller cell you should set a taller row height.

Comment: It appears you want to show a message if your data has no entries (no rows to display). Instead of trying to show a cell that fills the height of the table view, add a view with your text and show it on top of the table view.

Answer (score 0):

So `UITableView.automaticDimension` will tell the program to find the minimum height this cell can be without any clipping (to simplify it)

What you'll need to do is intercept the cell in

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if self.myData.isEmpty {
        return tableView.frame.height
    }

    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Assuming you show that cell when there Is no data to be shown, you can just do a check to see if you data array isEmpty, and if so, make the cell the height of the tableView

Comment: Thank you, bu It's not work:(